# Implementing another language before installation on ImpressPages 4.2.7

Tags: impresspages

I tried to implement default turkish language before installation on version 4.2.7:

**/install/Plugin/Install/sql/data.sql**

```
INSERT INTO `ip_language` (`abbreviation`, `title`, `languageOrder`, `isVisible`, `url`, `code`) VALUES ('TR', 'Türkçe', 1, 1, '', 'tr');
```

After installation i get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class '\Ip\Internal\Translations\Translator' not found in
>   /home/***/public_html/test/Ip/ServiceLocator.php on line 257

It was working same method on version 4.2.5 but doesnt work in this version. What changes on new version? What am i missing?

I tried like following:

```
INSERT INTO `ip_language` (`abbreviation`, `title`, `languageOrder`, `isVisible`, `url`, `code`) VALUES 
('EN', 'English', 1, 1, '', 'en'),
('TR', 'Türkçe', 1, 2, 'tr', 'tr');
```

Installation success but when i move turkish language to first, getting same error.

By the way, these method works perfect on localhost but doest work in live server.

Comment: Are you trying to change installation script so that you would have TR language installed by default?

Comment: Exactly! On 4.2.5 version, works great but 4.2.7 version same error always. Enable debug mode but only seen fatal error.

Comment: I test new method. Installed default Impress and added turkish language. When i enter /tr url, getting same error.

Comment: I realized that this issue general not only implementing default language. I submitted issue to GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue not about only ImpressPages. It's PHP bug about **setLocale()** function:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18556

**Fixed the issue:**:https://github.com/impresspages/ImpressPages/issues/610